# Want to add a timer circuit to shut down battery powered toy

Tags: integrated-circuit, 555, hobbyist

Would like to have:
Operates down to 3V,
Open drain/collector output,
Programmable with resistor/capacitor/other,
Integrated clock divider would be nice.

Was thinking of using a 555 chip to shut off the power in some battery powered toys, about a 2 minute shut off would be good.
Something close to the circuit below.

[image]

Is there a better way to do this?

An example of what I want to control:
This IKEA toy, all I remember is inserting a new set of freshly charged batteries and its drained within an hour or so. It would run into a corner of the room, stuck against the wall, whirring it battery out
https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/lillabo-battery-operated-locomotive-10433423/

[image]

However BRIO was very thoughtful in their design.
https://www.brio.us/products/all-products/railway/trains-wagon-and-vehicles/mighty-red-action-locomotive
[image]

The above train shuts down automatically after two minutes, which changes its battery replacement cycle from hours to several weeks.

I don't want to built a discrete circuit for this, I would prefer a single chip solution with minimal or zero external components.

Comment: as 555 has no internal divider. That answers the question in your last sentence. When we hence look at the rest of this question, it's a product recommendation question – and these are explicitly off-topic here. Can you rephrase your question to describe what you need (you already did a fairly good job, but you will need to tell us about your load, about the times you want your timer to time, why setting it via an RC circuit is desirable (as that's a very strange requirement!) and what you want to achieve with an internal divider. Then describe what your 555-based approach would have been!

Comment: Finally, ask something that helps you find a *solution* rather than a *chip to buy* – not only is that on-topic, it's probably also much more helpful to you :)

Comment: if I remember correctly, there is a version of the 555 timer that has an internal divider

Comment: @jsotola There is such a chip (that does not appear to be much of a success in the market)  but it fails the 3-12V requirement (1.2 to 5.5V only). And also not open-drain output.

Comment: a microcontroller may be the solution

Comment: As stated above please revise your question to be more design orientated, such as what you plan to use or what you have tried already.  As for a 555, it actually does have an internal resistor divider with the 2/3 Vcc available on pin 5 (Control Voltage).  As an alternative to a 555 there is an Analog Devices TimerBlox chip LTC6995, it includes a wide range of programmability using 1 to 3 resistors and works down to 2.25V.  As a last resort even a small PIC or ATtiny chip could provide programmable timing with a very minimal amount of code, some of these can use a 1.8V supply.

Comment: Not seeking a product recommendation. I was trying to add a timer function to some of these battery draining forever running toys of my children, so that they shut down after 2 minutes or so.

Comment: @Jean, that is a good start, if you revise your question with that as a main issue and showing some initial effort others here may vote to reopen the question.

Comment: Done. Added more context to the question.

Comment: @Jean, I'll try revising the question further.  If not acceptable feel free to edit again.

Comment: @Nedd, Thanks. Clearly articulates my thought.